# logstash @timestemp is not updated using date filter

Tags: logstash

I have the following filter:

```
date {
  match => [ "zeppelin_timestemp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ] 
  add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
  target = "@timestamp"
  }
```

The output is:

```
 {
           "message" => "INFO [2015-08-28 13:39:06,326] ({Thread-25} ZeppelinServer.java[run]:122) - Bye\r",
          "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2015-08-28T10:39:06.326Z",
              "host" => "127.0.0.1",
              "type" => "zeppelin",
         "log_level" => "INFO",
"zeppelin_timestemp" => "2015-08-28 13:39:06,326",
              "data" => "({Thread-25} ZeppelinServer.java[run]:122) - Bye\r",
              "tags" => [
    [0] "zeppelin_log_event"
],
             "debug" => "timestampMatched"
```

}

As you can see the date filter passed ok as I have the "debug" => "timestampMatched" set. but also
 **"@timestamp" => "2015-08-28T10:39:06.326Z" is not set.**

The original input is:
INFO [2015-08-28 13:39:06,326] ({Thread-25} ZeppelinServer.java[run]:122) - Bye

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's set correctly, just to UTC.  I'll bet you're 3 hours off UTC, right?

The big hint is the millisecond value - I doubt few sites generate, ship, and process a log in the same millisecond.